# Operator overloading (comparision operator) in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the comparision operator.

How can i overload the comparison operator == for this function? c++

```
template <class elemType>
    void ArrayList<elemType>::RetrieveItem(elemType & item, bool& found) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_element; i++)
        {
            if (data[i].getName() == item.getName())
            {
                found = true;
                item = data[n_element];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pay attention to this code - i think you can go out of bounds if array consist of n_element
item = data[n_element]; <-----------------

Answer (score -1):

from the looks of it, you are comparing 2 strings. overloading comparison operator would go into the class definition for whatever `getName()` returns

You can see lots of information regarding operator overloading [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/7839693)